# Not able to check the B2 cell using Offset in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, offset

I am trying to write a small if loop to check if the previous entry in the same column, but 1 row above is blank or not. If its blank, then the code deletes the existing data and goes to the empty cell in Column B. It works fine for all other cells. But right in the beginning when B2 is selected I think Offset (-2,0) creates an error which means I am not able to check if B2 is empty or not using this code.

Below is the code I am trying to use.

** I must admit my knowledge of VBA is pretty limited**

```
If ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0) = "" Then
 
ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0).Select
 
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = ""
 
MsgBox "You missed answering the a question, cannot proceed Further"
 
Exit Sub
 
End If
```

Comment: It throws an error because you can't go two rows up from B2, as you hint at. Maybe check if the cell's row is greater than 2 before attempting to `Offset`: `If ActiveCell.Row > 2 Then`.

Comment: Why are you using `.Offset(-2, 0)` (two rows above) when you said you wanted to check the cell 1 row above?

Comment: You've stated: "...But right in the beginning when B2 is selected I think Offset (-2,0) creates an error which means ***I am not able to check if B2 is empty or not using this code.***". Based on your code, `B2` will be checked when `B4` is the `ActiveCell`. You might need to change the lower bound of your loop to start at cell `B4` instead of `B2` but to be clearer on this you will need to update your question to either include your loop code or specify any assistance you need with getting it working.

Comment: Given that you admit to being a novice allow me to suggest that what you want to do can't be satisfactorily achieved with your approach. Start by reading up on *Worksheet events*, in particular the `Worksheet_Change` event. A modified version of our message is necessary when the user answers a question out of sequence. The event procedure can capture each answer and determine if the previous one was answered.